# Auto-generating Doctrine entities; custom parsing

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine 2.2.1 to reverse engineer a DB (YAML mappings), and subsequently generate the entity files.  Right now, I have it setup to use the Entity namespace.  The database names themselves are converted to camel case.

So... user_acl becomes:

```
<?php
namespace Entity;

// ...

class UserAcl {}
```

Is there a way to have user_acl generate a class with the following structure:

```
<?php
namespace Entity\User;

class Acl {}
```

So my question is... Can Doctrine use underscores to determine the namespace in lieu of using them to generate a camel caps-style class name?

Comment: Not without hacking the code.  The thing is, unless you have a gazillion entities or some real need for extra folders then it's much easier to just dump everything into one directory.  By doing so, entities will know about their fellow entities without know their namespace.  I too instinctively try to group similar entities together but in the case of D2 entities, the instinct should be suppressed.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  We can still dream!  Maybe Doctrine 3.